# Send reminder email at certain date using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to implement "reminder email" that will be sent on a certain date;

Migration:

```
Schema::create('todos', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('importance');            
    $table->date('when');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->string('to');
});
```

(email address will be the address of the user who created this reminder).

Command:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Todo;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Mail\EmailReminder;

class SendEmails extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'email:reminder';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Send reminder e-mails to a users';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct() //Todo $todo
    {
        parent::__construct();

        //$this->todo = $todo;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, $id, $todo)
    {

           $i = 0;
           $todo = Todo::whereMonth('when', '=', date('m'))->whereDay('when', '=', date('d'))->get();  

           foreach($todo as $todo)
           {
               $email = $todo->email;
               Mail::to($email)->send(new BirthdayReminder($todo));
               $i++; 
           }

    }
}
```

Mailable:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use App\Todo;


class EmailReminder extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $todo;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Todo $todo)
    {
        $this->todo = $todo;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {

        $todo = $this->todo;

        return $this->from('friendlyreminder@yourcompany.rs')
              ->view('emails.reminder',compact('todo'));
        //Mail::to(Auth::user()->email)->send(new EmailReminder());
    }

}
```

Kernel:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
   $schedule->command('email:reminder')->everyMinute();

}
```

The issue is, when I try php artisan email:reminder, I receive error message "Class App\Console\Commands\Request does not exist".

I'm really puzzled and did check similar questions here on StackOverlow and googled it, but can't manage to figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This will send all those email every minute of that day, repeatedly.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but this was posted almost 3 year ago, it would be really funny if I was still stuck on the same question for 3 years

Comment: That was not an answer to your question, just a constatation so other viewers get a sense of how code works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `use Request;` to the imports at the beginning of your console command's file.
Because `Request` is a facade and it belongs to the root namespace or, put a `\` before its every usage.

Comment: Thanks, it did work. I also had to amend "public function handle(Request $request, $id, $todo)" to "public function handle(Todo $todo)"