# Laravel send email reminders at specified date and timing selected by the users

Tags: laravel

i am making a reminder feature.
users select date and timing for the meeting and select the reminder date and time.

fields

user_id, meeting_date , meeting_time and reminder_date , reminder_time.

i don't seem to understand how to send an auto email to a specified reminder_date and reminder in laravel.

Comment: I think you could make a cronjob for that. I will not write the code for you, but you can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53031911/send-reminder-email-at-certain-date-using-laravel) post for example, or google for some example or tutorial with something like "laravel send email on specific date"

Comment: how resource greedy is this cronjob for the server to check after after every mint or 10 mint?

Comment: I think that the problem with the server resources would not be the cronjob itself, but the amount of data it have to check, since it would have to make a query to DB every time. However, there are ways to improve the performance if it needed, for example by removing from your table the reminders that have already passed

Comment: Another idea that comes to mind now, would be to have 2 tasks in the cronjob. One that runs once a day, retrieve only the reminders of that day and save them in the cache. And another one that runs every minute or every 10 minutes, checking only the data that was saved in the cache.

Comment: I meet this problem nearly. My solution is create cronjob run per minute. And you can query matched results in current time. If query have results, just take it and send for all subcribers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a laravel cronjob through laravel console command.

Something like send: reminder which will send an autogenerated email once it gets the same date which you sets for the reminder.

According to me you should set the time for the cron job as every one hour or every 30 minutes